# BeautifulSoup drops text when fixing up broken markup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to Python, but what the heck... This is kind of a weird question so I will do my best to explain it as throughly as I can:

I'm busy trying to write a script in Python that checks a webpage for a specific change (a number flipping from 0 to 1 basically). When that change occurs, the script will proceed onto doing something else. Unfortunately, I have not been able to get to that point yet because I'm having trouble even parsing the HTML because a lot of the HTML is missing when `BeautifulSoup` gets a hold of it! (At least, this is what I claim.)

Let's step through this: I'm using `BeautifulSoup` and `Mechanize` for this. First, I find a form on the webpage and select it, changing controls in the form as I need. (I have verified that all of the controls change as I expect.) After this, I submit the form and then call a helper function I wrote called `process_results()`:

```
...
form = list(client.forms())[1]
client.select_form('ttform');
...
# Modify controls
...
client.submit()
process_results(client)
```

`process_results()` just checks what the client got back. First of all, depending on what was put into the form, you can get invalid search results, so I would like to search for the error message that displays on the webpage and see if it exists. I use `BeautifulSoup` to do this:

```
# Processes search results.
def process_serach_results(cli):

    html = cli.response().read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    ...
```

The statement that evaluates if the piece of code in question appears on the page looks like:

```
...
if (soup.find('td', attr = {'class' : 'msgarea'}) != None):
    # Do something...
    ...
```

This will never evaluate to be true because it cannot find the tag I'm describing. I decided to print out both the response directly from `Mechanize` and from `BeautifulSoup`, and this is what I got (shortened):

`Mechanize` prints the code I'm out to find, which means that the response is coming back correctly:

```
...
<TD class=msgarea>
<B class=important_msg>There was a problem with your request:</B>
<BR>
<BR>
<li class=red_msg>...</li>
...
</TD></TR></TABLE><P></DIV>
...
```

This is the last piece of HTML that shows up from `BeautifulSoup`:

```
...
<span class="pageheaderlinks">
<a ... > MENU </a>
|
<a ... > SITE MAP </a>
|
</span></td></tr></table></div></body></html>
```

In fact, here's that same HTML from `Mechanize`:

```
...
<SPAN class="pageheaderlinks">
<A ... >MENU</A>
|
<A ... >SITE MAP</A>
|
<--! Notice how this continues -->
<A ... >HELP</A>
|
<A ... >EXIT</A>
</span>
...
```

The problem is that it seems `BeautifulSoup` is omitting a large piece of HTML from the end of what `Mechanize`'s Browser is reporting. This could be a problem with how I'm going about things, but at this point, I'm incredibly lost.

Does anyone know what could be causing this to occur? Thanks! :)

Comment: what happens if you explicitly pass the HTML (wrapped in `<html><body>` tags) as a string to BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Install `html5lib` and see if that helps BeautifulSoup parse it more leniently.

Comment: @Blender, wow. That did it. I never would have thought... Can you make that an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BeautifulSoup supports [a bunch of different HTML parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). Python's builtin parser isn't very fast or lenient (meaning that it has a hard time making sense of invalid HTML), so it chokes on your HTML.

Try installing `lxml`, which is more lenient and much faster. If that doesn't work, `html5lib` is your best bet, as it's the most lenient but also the slowest.

Comment: after spending useless hours debugging my code.. and finally resolved after using html5lib... thank you so much... code re-written in just one line as: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")` and it has done magic.. and all soup stayed intact... previously missed many parts of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Blender's answer was correct, but this code shows how badly the old parser ruins the markup and may prove useful when hunting down similar problems.

```
# fails with bs3, works with bs4
bs3 = True

if bs3:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
else:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

mechanize = """
    <TD class=msgarea>
    <B class=important_msg>There was a problem with your request:</B>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <li class=red_msg>...</li>
    </TD></TR></TABLE><P></DIV>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(mechanize) 
# the default parser worked just fine, see?
print soup.prettify()

print 'is important_msg?', soup.find('b').attrs
print 'is msgarea?', soup.find('td').attrs
print 'is td?', soup.find(class_='msgarea').name
print 'is contents?', soup.find('td', class_='msgarea').contents[:5], '...'
```

It took me a while to debug because bs4 wasn't failing, so I figured I'd perhaps save the next guy to come by here. This is the truly bizarre output using bs3 which can find the tag by `class` but not by `name`:

```
<td class="msgarea">
 <b class="important_msg">
  There was a problem with your request:
 </b>
 <br />
 <br />
 <li class="red_msg">
  ...
 </li>
</td>
<p>
</p>
is important_msg? [(u'class', u'important_msg')]
is msgarea? [(u'class', u'msgarea')]
is td?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bs-fail.py", line 24, in <module>
    print 'is td?', soup.find(class_='msgarea').name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```